# I want to calculate and adapt the gradient by myself in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to calculate and adapt the gradient by myself in tensorflow.
I want to calculate the gradient for one of the multiple outputs by myself, and adapt 0 for the rest of the outputs.

I have tested building the model with the following simple program and trying to adapt it by setting one gradient to a constant value and the other gradient to 0, but I am not getting the desired output.

What should I give to apply_gradients?

I don't know much about tensorflow, so I would appreciate if you could kindly tell me about it

```
def cmodel():
    in_ = Input(shape=(1,))
    x=in_
    x=Dense(16)(x)
    x=Activation('relu')(x)
    x=Dense(2)(x)
    x=Activation('linear')(x)
    
    model = Model(inputs=in_, outputs=[x])
    return model

model=cmodel()
model.compile(optimizer=Nadam(learning_rate=0.005))

mylist2=[]
for i in range(100):
    g=tf.constant([-0.3,0])

    model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(g, model.trainable_variables))
    print('num:',model.predict(np.array([1])))
    mylist2.append(model.predict(np.array([1]))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do.
In fact, what you are doing is applying the values -3 to the trainable variable of the first layer, i.e. to the kernel of the first dense layer and 0 to the bias.
For example, if you want to modify the first layer only, you can define `g=tf.constant([-0.3, 3., 0., 0.])`. You could also get the training variables of the first layer: `model.layers[1].trainable_variables` and apply the gradient.